Filter current step by previous step
I have web traffic data for each page visited by a visitor ID.  We have a "funnel" where visitors go from Step A to Step B to Step C, etc.  Consider something like registering for a new account with multiple steps.
It's possible to reach individual steps independently, but in general, they go in order A, B, C, etc.  What I want to do is get a list of all unique visitors to A, then count only B where the visitor existed in set A, then count C where they existed in set B, etc.  If this were just two or three steps it could be pretty simple and/or manual, but there are many.  I am looking for the most efficient logic to get these results.  I considered a CTE but I'm really not quite sure how to connect it to itself.
Any thoughts about a logical (and performant/efficient) way to do this on tens of millions of records?  Thanks!
Some sample data:



visitor_id
step
sequence




1
A
1


1
B
2


2
A
1


2
B
2


2
C
3


3
B
2


3
C
3



The desired output would NOT include visitor ID #3 because they did NOT start with Step A.
Desired output:



step
unique visitor count




A
1000


B
950


C
800




You're gonna need some column specifying the sequence of the steps before this can be achievable

The format of your data/layout of the DB is not the best.  There should be a table with parent/child relationships and not all combined into 1 string at a time.

@siggemannen that's kinda what I was getting at.  I can do a rownum over order by step, so assuming that exists, what next?

@Brad yeah, agreed, but it doesn't exist and I don't have any control over it.  It's an outside data source that I don't own.  Maybe a rownum over order by step is sufficient, best I can do.

is the order always A => B and B =>C, is C => A not possible?

@siggemannen consider that any order is possible.  I'm counting DISTINCT visitor ID, so that helps with any situation where a visitor goes A to B to C, THEN B to C again.  Just count that once.

Ok, so what's the output you're interested in? For example for the table above. I don't get it to be honest

Desired output
Step A - 1000 (count of unique visitors to Step A)
Step B - 950 (50 visitors FROM STEP A didn't move past Step A)
Step C - 800 (150 visitors FROM STEP B didn't move past Step B)
Just note that all 950 visitors from line two did go to Step A first.  This excludes any visitors who went directly to Step B without visiting Step A first.

What would sequence be if a visitor went from A->B->C->B->C or A->B->C->A->B->C

@Geezer the sequence would be the same (in your two examples would be 1 2 3 2 3, and 1 2 3 1 2 3), but because the counts are DISTINCT the "extra" visits to steps B and C would just "fall out", not be counted.

so if a Visitor started at B and went to C then the sequence would be 1,2 or 2,3?

Is then step A always sequence 1 and step B sequence 2 etc? I think you need to give a bit more sample data and explain the logic and all the corner cases.

@Geezer I only want to include visitors who visited Step A, so that's my base.

@Charlieface A will always be 1, B will always be 2, etc.  The results here MUST go to in order, but don't necessarily have to go through all steps.  If we say there are only 3 steps (A, B, C) the results will show how many started (visited A), how many moved on (visited B), etc.  I want to see the fallout - in the desired output the fallout from Step A to Step B is 50.

So for the sample data the results would be A: 2   B: 3   C: 2 or A: 2   B: 2   C: 1 ? You could use LAG and then conditional aggregation https://dbfiddle.uk/Uweuouos

Assuming:

a valid count of visitors always begins from step A and,
they must follow the correct sequence, i.e. not skip a step and ,
maximum possible steps are 26, letters of the alphabet

then this maybe one answer.
I'm using a Tally table to dynamically generate the alphabet
CREATE TABLE dbo.VisitorSteps (
    visitor_id INT,
    step CHAR(1),
    seq INT
);

INSERT INTO dbo.VisitorSteps (visitor_id, step, seq)
VALUES
 (1, 'A', 1), --started at A
(1, 'B', 2), --got to B

(2, 'A', 1), --Quit after A

(3, 'A', 1), -- started at A
(3, 'B', 2),
(3, 'C', 3), -- got to C
(3, 'B', 2), -- then went back to B (dup)
(3, 'C', 3), -- then onto C again (dup)

(4, 'B', 1), -- started at B so exclude this Visitor
(4, 'C', 2),

(5, 'A', 1), --started at A
(5, 'B', 2),
(5, 'C', 3); -- got to C


;WITH    
     lv0 AS (SELECT 0 g UNION ALL SELECT 0)
    ,lv1 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b) -- 4
    ,lv2 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv1 b) -- 16
    ,lv3 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv2 a CROSS JOIN lv2 b) -- 256
    ,Tally (n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM lv3)
    ,Alphabet AS (
SELECT  Alpha=Char(T.n+64), seq=T.n 
FROM    Tally T
WHERE   T.n <= 26
) , _data
AS(
    SELECT   V.*, A.Alpha
        ,chk = iif(A.seq <> V.seq, 0, 1) /*not skipping a step*/
    FROM Alphabet A 
    outer apply dbo.VisitorSteps V 
    WHERE   V.Step = A.Alpha
)
SELECT   unique_visitor_count=
            count(distinct D.visitor_id)
        ,D.step
FROM _data D 
WHERE   D.chk = 1
GROUP BY D.step ;

Output:


It seems you could use LAG to get the previous sequence for each row, then use conditional aggregation to filter it to only those rows which are sequential.
You can add in FIRST_VALUE and check that as well if you want to only start from sequence 1.
WITH PrevValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      LAG(t.sequence) OVER (PARTITION BY t.visitor_id ORDER BY t.sequence) AS prev_sequence,
      FIRST_VALUE(t.sequence) OVER (PARTITION BY t.visitor_id ORDER BY t.sequence ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS min_sequence
    FROM YourTable t
)
SELECT
  t.step,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN prev_sequence + 1 < sequence OR min_sequence <> 1 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS count_continuing_visitors
FROM PrevValues t
GROUP BY
  t.step;

db<>fiddle
